# MikTeX 2.9 without list of packages in settings program

Tags: packages, miktex, updating

Today I updated MikTeX and the process aborted.  After that, the **program does not show the list of packages** in the update (admin) program.  I changed the package repository address and the program informs the following error:

---

Error report:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Unknown package.
Data: uni-wtal-ger
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
Line: 1026
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (build 2600)
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Configuración local\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Configuración local\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Datos de programa\MiKTeX\2.9
```

---

After that, the list of packages is empty.

I searched the uni-wtal-ger package and found it in `C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages`.  This file has the following content:

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:TPM="http://texlive.dante.de/">
<rdf:Description about="http://www.miktex.org/packages/uni-wtal-get">
<TPM:Name>uni-wtal-get</TPM:Name>
<TPM:Creator>mpc</TPM:Creator>
<TPM:Title>Citation style for literary studies at the University of Wuppertal.</TPM:Title>
<TPM:Version>0.1</TPM:Version>
<TPM:TargetSystem></TPM:TargetSystem>
<TPM:Description>The package defines a biblatex citation style based on the author-title style of biblatex-dw. The citations are optimised for literary studies in faculty of humanities at the Bergische Universität Wuppertal.</TPM:Description>
<TPM:RunFiles size="8916">texmf\bibtex\bib\uni-wtal-ger\germanistik.bib texmf\tex\latex\uni-wtal-ger\uni-wtal-ger.bbx texmf\tex\latex\uni-wtal-ger\uni-wtal-ger.cbx texmf\tpm\packages\uni-wtal-get.tpm</TPM:RunFiles>
<TPM:DocFiles size="71811">texmf\doc\latex\uni-wtal-ger\germanistik.pdf texmf\doc\latex\uni-wtal-ger\README</TPM:DocFiles>
<TPM:SourceFiles size="4531">texmf\source\uni-wtal-ger-src.tar.bz2</TPM:SourceFiles>
<TPM:TimePackaged>1304690215</TPM:TimePackaged>
<TPM:MD5>5cfacd1eb764f317970a3f8fabd04455</TPM:MD5>
<TPM:CTAN path="/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/uni-wtal-ger"/>
<TPM:Copyright owner="Carsten A. Dahlmann" year="2011"/>
<TPM:License type="lppl1.3"/></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF>
```

---

After I deleted this file, I repeated the process of changing the package repository, to force a reread of the package list.  **The error repeats again**.

I looked before posting the related questions to the title of my question and searched for `uni-wtal-ger` getting zero references.

I use Windows XP SP3 with MikTeX 2.9.

This happened once one year ago and the problem was resolved by someone retiring the difficult package.

Does someone has an idea of how can I restore the package list or should I wait that the list of packages be repaired on the servers?

Comment: This problem hapens to me, too. I reinstalled MiKTeX, nothing changes.

Comment: I updated today and had no problems. I'm using the repository at fu-berlin.de. The package manager list doesn't show a `uni-wtal-ger` package but only `uni-wtal-get` (which looks like a typo as it contains files with name `uni-wtal-ger`) and a search on CTAN finds only `uni-wtal-get.tar.lzma`. Synchronize in the package manager the repository, do it as admin and as user (you can also do it on the command line, see the documentation).

Comment: Good morning. From yesterday on, I had that problem on several Win-Installations, too. There was no matter which repo I used. I even tried a rsync-mirrored (private) aktual updated CTAN.org repo...
My way around was using the "Package Manager" - this is working fine for me...
Good luck.

Comment: Another strange behaviour: After beeing able to install the package `uni-wtal-ger` it is again unknown in **MiKTeX Options (Admin)** _Packages_ (Tab)...

Comment: The correct package should be `uni-wtal-ger`, but in CTAN, MiKTeX named it as `uni-wtal-get` see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-wtal-ger

Comment: This was clearly a passing MiKTeX issue, for which the Q&A format here is not well-suited. I'll close it.