# How to fix the MiKTeX bug about uni-wtal-ger / uni-wtal-get?

Tags: packages, errors, miktex

I encountered the exact problem as [MikTeX 2.9 without list of packages in settings program](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17777/miktex-2-9-without-list-of-packages-in-settings-program).

Now I figure out it may be a bug of MiKTeX. It misnamed one package. The correct package should be `uni-wtal-ger`, but MiKTeX named it as `uni-wtal-get`, so miktex reports it do not know `uni-wtal-ger`. See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-wtal-ger and also

[image: uni-wtal-ger info]

[image: error msg]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Miktex can name its package as it like. The miktex package is on CTAN in `systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/uni-wtal-get.tar.lzma`. The
 `uni-wtal-get` may be a typo but it should not be a problem as long as the miktex databases use this name too. As it works fine for me try at first to synchronize the repository databases (package manager, menu repository).

Comment: Yes I can use package manager as you see the first pic, but I can not use Miktex options/package to generate the package tree which is more organized.

Comment: I see. I hadn't realized that you meant miktex options (mo.exe) and not mpm.exe. It is probably a type in a miktex database. I have made a bug report.

Comment: It seems fixed in the recent update!